# Crawlspider rule not working

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to build a spider to scrape the data for courses at NY institute of Technology using the scrapy framework using python... following is my spider (nyitspider.py). Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule, BaseSpider, Spider
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

from nyit_sample.items import NyitSampleItem


class nyitspider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'nyitspider'
allowed_domains = ['nyit.edu']
start_urls = ['http://www.nyit.edu/academics/courses/']

rules = (
    Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(
         allow=('.*/academics/courses', ),
    )),

Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(
         allow=('.*/academics/courses/[a-z][a-z][a-z]-[a-z][a-z]-[0-9][0-9]    [0-9]/', ),
    ), callback='parse_item'),

)

def parse_item(self, response):
    item = Course()
    item["institute"] = 'New York Institute of Technology'
    item['site'] = 'www.nyit.edu'
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="course_catalog_table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a').extract()[0]
item['id'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="course_catalog_table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a').extract()[0]
    item['credits'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="course_catalog_table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]').extract()[0]
    item['description'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="course_catalog_table"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/text()[1]').extract()[0]



    yield item
```

Comment: what can we derive from this?
2017-03-17 07:20:59 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6026
2017-03-17 07:20:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.nyit.edu/academics/courses/> (referer: None) ['cached']

Comment: First of all, you can remove `tbody` tag from all your xpath expression. It added by a browser and response from the page doesn't have it. And try to change regex in your second Rule to `r'\/academics\/courses\/(.*)'` (first rule you also can remove).

Answer (score 0):

You have to correctly declare the item in the parse_item method, and the method should return something. Here's a suggestion, but you have to refine it:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule, BaseSpider, Spider
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

from nyit_sample.items import NyitSampleItem


class nyitspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'nyitspider'
    allowed_domains = ['nyit.edu']
    start_urls = ['http://www.nyit.edu/academics/courses/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(
             allow=('.*/academics/courses', ),
        ), callback='parse_item'),   
        Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(
             allow=('.*/academics/courses/[a-z][a-z][a-z]-[a-z][a-z]-[0-9][0-9]    [0-9]/', ),
        ), callback='parse_item'),

    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = NyitSampleItem()
        item['institute'] = 'New York Institute of Technology'
        item['site'] = 'www.nyit.edu'
        item['title'] = response.xpath('string(//*[@id="course_catalog_table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a)').extract()[0]
        item['id'] = response.xpath('string(//*[@id="course_catalog_table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a)').extract()[0]
        item['credits'] = response.xpath('string(//*[@id="course_catalog_table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3])').extract()[0]
        item['description'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="course_catalog_table"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/text()[1]').extract()[0]
        return item
```